# how to insert an alphanumeric number?

Tags: excel

I need to define a formula...so that the first column should consist of the following series ... 
992aa
992bb
.
.
.
.

im using ms office 2007

Comment: You need to update your question with more details. Are you trying to *automate* this in Excel? With what programming language? What code do you already have? What have you already tried, and why doesn't it work?

Comment: Write it with the keyboard maybe? Your question is very unclear! Are you intending doing this with VBA etc? Give all the facts so the there is a question to answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create a formula that displays `992` and *increment* the letter on each row, here is what you can use (on the **first row** but you can change the `96` depending on the first row):

```
="992" & CHAR(96 + ROW()) & CHAR(96 + ROW())
```

At least, this formula will **give you a good start** to find the right solution.